# How to refresh home page everytime when navigating from a any Page in the flutter mobile app?

Tags: flutter, callback, page-refresh, banking

## I tried to attempt the following please help I'm new in a flutter:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Refresh on Go Back',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  int id = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Data: $id',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Second Page'),
              onPressed: navigateSecondPage,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  void refreshData() {
    id++;
  }

  onGoBack(dynamic value) {
    refreshData();
    setState(() {});
  }

  void navigateSecondPage() {
    Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage());
    Navigator.push(context, route).then(value) => onGoBack(callBackId));
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Second Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go Back'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here I'm trying to implement a functionality to refresh the home page every time when navigating back from other pages within my application. I was only using this piece of code for testing purposes I want to implement this code in my Flutter banking app connecting to a banking institution API Thank You in advance.

Comment: Usually you use Provider like package to listen to changes in items. If there's changes then the Widget rebuilds itself. Are you sure this is the code, it has errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For refreshing the page everytime, you need to call

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
```

And Inside this `initState` you can call your refresh data method.

When you comes from any other page to home page your method is called first.

**Note:** Your page is `StatefulWidget` for calling this method.

Comment: can you please give me an example of using this method

Comment: By your code, can you tell me when you navigate to homepage your id is being increased or not?

Comment: yes  the Id increments whenever i navigate to Homepage

Comment: whats you want next can you explain in brief?

Comment: can you give me a code sample example to implement this in a simple code with just back button maybe only for homepage and secondpage

Comment: yes to show the code for refreshing the page and the methods